# Cross Account Call to CloudFormation API From Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I am currently calling CloudFormation CreateStack API -     **createStack**, **createChangeSet** from a Lambda in Account-A. I am able to call these and the cloudformation stack gets created in Account A.

Now I want to execute the cloudformation stack in some other account let's say Account B. Can my lambda in Account A can call **createStack**, **createChangeSet** APIs in account B. Basically I want the resources to be created in different account.

How can I do this, which permission do I need to set and where.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes this can be done.

One thing to consider, it may be quite easy to simply deploy the lambda to account B and invoke it there to effect your desired result.

To run it in Account A and have it create resources in Account B, you will need to ensure account A allows the lambda permission to call out to cloudformation for Account B. This would be done by examining (and modifying if necessary) the IAM policy for your lambda role.

For the lambda in account A to be able to effect change in account B, your CloudFormation client in the lambda needs to use credentials for an IAM role or user defined in account B which will allow it permissions to createStack, createChangeSet, etc, plus it may also need permissions for the resources it is creating (e.g. Dynamo createTable)

Answer (score 1):

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/aws-building-a-secure-cross-account-continuous-delivery-pipeline/ contains details and code examples of how to do this.

Basically you need to change the role arn used for each deployment. Codepipeline will then run the deployment using that arn. If that arn is in a different account, the deployment happens in that account.